# CSV converting date from US to UK format only changes some, not all

Tags: excel, csv

I have a CSV file that contains a few date columns. It was created with the US format of dd/mm/yyyy. I need to switch those dates to the UK dd/mm/yyyy. Saving the file seems well and good. But when I reopen the file many of the dates appear without the zeros if they had one as the first digit. An example:

saved as - 03/03/2012
when re-opened - 3/3/2012

I'm using Excel 2007 and saved from xlsx to all possible CSV options (mac, windows, ms-dos..)

Anyone know why this is happening, or more importantly a solution?

Comment: Many of the dates, or all of the dates? Can you show examples of date which do and don't remain "as saved"? There's no formatting saved in a CSV, so when you open it Excel will do its best to interpret the contents (depending on your local settings): if dates aren't in the format it expects then results may not be as desired....  Compare the cell formats for the different values : you may see both "Date" and "General" (these values were not interpreted as dates)

Comment: It's a lot of the dates. The zeros just get stripped away for some reason. My local time is the US (the xlsx was created here), if that helps. Yes, when I was randomly checking cells some were general. Even stranger than what is already strange, the general format ones were the ones that looked correct! The ones without the zeros were date. Here is a screen shot. The ones on the left are how they need to look (before saving). The right is how they appear after saving..
[link](http://devarea51.com/csv.png)
Thanks fr your time.

Comment: If you're on a US system then Excel is going to be expecting US-format dates: when you open a CSV it automatically converts "valid" dates, skipping the rest.  If you want to tell Excel what format to expect dates in, then you can go through the Text import wizard (change the .csv extension to .txt), which allows you to specify a DMY format (instead of the US-default MDY)

Comment: @TimWilliams The Text Import wizard works for .CSV with no conversion necessary.

Comment: If the dates are already formatted as you want them in the CSV (i.e., if they were entered as text, not as dates, in the original .xlsx file), you could choose to import them as Text in the import wizard to avoid Excel messing with your data.

Comment: Thank you for your help Tim. I renamed the csv file to txt and used the import wizard making the date format changed as you suggested. During the wizard in the preview pane all the dates looked correct. However when I click finish the dates are still the same file opens :( zeros are missing. As a matter of fact, everything looked as it did before doing the import. Is there something I'm missing or is it possible the original file is corrupt??

Comment: @Excellll - Yes, it will, but I prefer the File>>Open approach becuase it will import the data without creating a "connection" in the workbook.

Comment: By default, leading zeros won't be maintained.  If you really want that then I think you'd need to change your system setting for the default "short date" in "Regional and Language options" control panel widget.

Answer (score 0):

For windows users, go to the control panel, pick regional and language options and pick the date format you want.  In windows XP, the option for dd/mm/YYYY format only appears if you pick "English (United Kingdom)".  I have not tried the export, but this fixed the import of a csv file.